# How to disable drawer navigation swipe for one of navigator screen only?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a custom navigation drawer and on a particular screen, I don't want it available.

This is my short code.

This navigator is also being included by the switch navigator. I have dig in git-hub and other forums and nothing is currently working. Am I missing something? Is there someone who made it to work?

```
const UserNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    ProductListScreen: {screen: ProductListScreen},
    ProductHistoryScreen: {
      screen: ProductHistoryScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
      }
    }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'ProductListScreen',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
})

export default createAppContainer(UserNavigation)
```

There is also a [working code on expo](https://snack.expo.io/@riwu/stack-nav-lock-drawer) but I try and and results in double navigators displaying, and also in the screen where I don't want to show the drawer it appears. This is my attempt from referring to expo code

```
const UserStackNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  ProductListScreen: {screen: ProductListScreen},
  ProductHistoryScreen: {
    screen: ProductHistoryScreen
  }
})

const UserNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  UserStackNavigation: UserStackNavigation
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'UserStackNavigation',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
})

UserStackNavigation.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  drawerLockMode: navigation.state.index === 0 ? 'unlocked' : 'locked-closed',
});
export default createAppContainer(UserNavigation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that i was using Ignite to generate my project template and the react-navigation version was fixed at 3.0.0. And after watching the last comment at [this link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5292) I realized that it wasn't any issue with my syntax.

So I deleted my packed.lock.json, yarn.lock, node_modules folder, in package.json I set the version as ^3.0.0 in order to get the latest version.

After all this I did a yarn install for getting a full package update. With this change my react-navigation-drawer went from 1.0.1 to 1.3.0 and this fixed the problem.

Also made some changes to my navigation which now looks like this:

```
export default class UserNavigation extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <Nav />
  }
}

const Nav = createAppContainer(
  createDrawerNavigator(
    {
      ProductListScreen: {screen: ProductListScreen},
      ProductHistoryScreen: {
        screen: ProductHistoryScreen,
          navigationOptions:{
            drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
          }
      }
    }, {
      initialRouteName: 'ProductListScreen',
      contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 15):

You can set options per screen using "swipeEnabled" property. Please take a look to related page of docs;

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#options

```
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Feed">
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="Feed"
    component={Feed}
    options={{ swipeEnabled: false }}
  />
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="Profile"
    component={Profile}
    options={{ drawerLabel: 'Profile' }}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>);}
```

Answer (score 6):

In v5 u can use `<Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }} ...>...</Drawer.Navigator>`

Comment: The original question is how to disable it in a specific screen only.

Answer (score 6):

I have added the navigation setup code for disabling side menu for specific screen, This may helpful for someone.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

import LoginScreen from '../LoginScreen'
import PasswordScreen from '../PasswordScreen'
import HomeScreen from '../HomeScreen'


const Stack = createStackNavigator()
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()
const sideMenuDisabledScreens = ['Login', 'Password']

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator 
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} 
      drawerPosition="right"
      drawerContent={(props) => <SideMenu {...props} />}
    >
    <Drawer.Screen 
      name="Initial"
      component={StackNavigator}
      options={({ route }) => {
        const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Login'
        if (sideMenuDisabledScreens.includes(routeName))
            return ({swipeEnabled: false})
      }} 
    />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Password' component={PasswordScreen} options={{gestureEnabled: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function MainNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MainNavigator
```

App.js has the following code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MainStackNavigator from './src/navigation/MainStackNavigator';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <MainStackNavigator />
        </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this was exactly what i needed and worked! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To disable swipe/gesture in a single route in React Navigation V5:

Import helper to get current route name

`import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';`

Check if the route name is the same as the route you want to disable swipe/gesture

```js
options={({ route }) => {
   const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
   return {
     swipeEnabled: routeName !== 'Profile',
   };
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `swipeEnabled` property can help, but the drawer could still be triggered for other reasons (for example, an action can programatically open it).

If you want to make sure that the drawer doesn't show at all in some cases, and you are able to detect the condition globally, you can use `drawerStyle: { display: 'none' }` in `screenOptions`:

```
const screenOptions = {
    drawerStyle: {
        display: 'none',
    },
    // ...
};

<Drawer.Navigator
    drawerContent={({ navigation }) => (
        <DrawerContent navigation={navigation} />
    )}
    screenOptions={screenOptions}
>
    {'...'}
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

In my case, I don't want to show the drawer if the user is not authenticated, so I define the display: 'none' in that case.